# Query to include if condition in addField

Tags: 7, database

How can I use the following SQL query with code that calls `db_select()`?

```sql
SELECT N_en.nid AS en_nid, IF(N_lan.translate = 1, 'Outdated', 'New') as lan_translated
  FROM node N_en
  LEFT JOIN node N_lan ON N_lan.tnid = N_en.nid
```

The following code does not work.

```php
$query = db_select('node', 'N_en')->extend('PagerDefault');
$query->addField('N_en', 'nid', 'en_nid');   
$query->addField('N_lan', 'translate', 'lan_translated');
$query->leftJoin('node', 'N_lan', 'N_en.nid=N_lan.tnid AND N_lan.language=:lang', array(':lang' => $userLan));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add an expression](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7):

```
...
$query->addExpression("IF(N_lan.translate = 1, 'Outdated', 'New')", 'lan_translated');
....
```